# How do I solve this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I must admit I am slightly confused how to attack this one:

$$3y^\prime \cdot y^{\prime\prime}= y + y^2 +1$$

Comment: Do you want a general solution or a special one or general information about the form of solutions? Note e.g. that the right hand side is always positive. It follows that all solutions are either increasing and concave up ($y' > 0, y''>0$) or decreasing and concave down ($y' < 0, y'' < 0$). That's information about the general solution behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I think that a general analytical solution is not feasible, so I'd be happy with any reasonable approximate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y'=0$ in an open interval, then on such interval $y(x)=c$ where $c$ is a constant such that
$$
0 = c + c^2 + 1
$$
If you are looking for real valued functions, no such $c$ exists, so that we may assume that $y'\neq0$. Therefore, we can multiply both sides by $y'$:
$$
3(y')^2y'' = (y+y^2+1)y'
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
  \frac{\rm d}{\rm d x} (y')^3
=
  \frac{\rm d}{\rm d x} (\textstyle{\frac12 y^2 + \frac13 y^3 + y})
$$
The boundary data gives you the constant $a$ such that
$$
  y'
=
  \sqrt[3]{\textstyle{\frac12 y^2 + \frac13 y^3 + y + a}}
$$
Now you have
$$
  x-x_0
=
  \int_{x_0}^x
  {
    \frac{{\rm d}y}{\sqrt[3]{\frac12 y^2 + \frac13 y^3 + y + a}}
  }
$$
Letting $F(x)=\int_{x_0}^x
  {
    \frac{{\rm d}y}{\sqrt[3]{\frac12 y^2 + \frac13 y^3 + y + a}}
  }$ you have $y=F^{-1}$.